# is there any difference in maven dependency for Netflix zuul and ribbon while upgrading to Spring boot 2.5.1 and spring cloud 2020.0.3

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

I am trying to upgrade my spring boot version from 2.1.5.RELEASE to 2.5.1, so I have changed the spring cloud version from Greenwich.RELEASE to 2020.0.3 according to release train Spring Boot compatibility for spring cloud. I am also using spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul and spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon in my project. The issue I am facing is when I build the maven, I'm getting error as follows

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:jar is missing. @ com.xx.xxx.xxx:[unknown-version], C:\Users\xx\pom.xml, line xx, column xx
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon:jar is missing. @ com.xx.xxx.xxxh:[unknown-version], C:\Users\xx\pom.xml, line xx, column xx
```

My pom file is as follows

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </parent>
    <repositories>
    </repositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

could anyone help to resolve this error, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Numerous Netflix-related modules that were previously in maintenance mode have been [removed in Spring Cloud 2020](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes). This includes Ribbon and Zuul which you are using. The Spring Cloud team [recommend](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now#spring-cloud-netflix-projects-entering-maintenance-mode) replacing Ribbon with Spring Cloud Loadbalancer and Zuul with Spring Cloud Gateway.

Answer (score 2):

spring-cloud and netflix-zuul will work as following versions.

```
spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.1.3.RELEASE
java.version: 1.8
spring-cloud.version: Greenwich.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul: 2.1.0.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client: 2.1.0.RELEASE
jackson-dataformat-xml: 2.9.9
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server: 2.1.0.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

> Spring removed zuul after 2.4.0 so it better to use below versions for smooth excution.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>


<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```